# Debian update: how to get more readable diff output?

Tags: debian, apt-get, diff

I like working with apt-get on servers, but it's very cumbersome to go through the diffs of config files when upgrading a system to a new Debian version.

Ideally it should be easy to hide changes in comments.
Alternatively, it would already help to at least have colors.

I didn't find a way to configure diff globally or specifically for apt-get.